# Fetch Records from columns with a substring character vector matching column names in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, substring, match

I want to fetch only rows from columns that is part of the character vector containing the sub string. Example below:

### My Table and List

> My Table's columns header seperated by | as below.Just typing many rows
>
> p1.abc.1| p1.dce.2|p1.efg.2|p2.abc.2|p2.dce.2|p2.qar.3|
>
> My List is as follows
>   list_1 = ('abc','def','efg')

### My Expected Output

> To return all the columns that partially matches with the string in the list.
>
> For example:
>   The output should return all the rows from the below columns
>
> p1.abc.1| p1.dce.2|p1.efg.2|p2.abc.2|p2.dce.2|
>
> Any help here would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you post a reproducible example. Give us some toy data that fits your specs and show us exactly what the desired output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## simulate the data frame with the given column names 

  df <- data.frame(p1.abc.1 = rnorm(10),
               p1.dce.2 = rnorm(10),
               p1.efg.2 = rnorm(10),
               p2.abc.2 = rnorm(10),
               p2.dce.2 = rnorm(10),
               p2.qar.3 = rnorm(10))

## your list 

list_1 <-  c('abc','def','efg') 

## sapply to loop, grep to find the matches
## unique and unlist to get the indeces 

z <- unique(unlist(sapply(list_1,function(x) grep( x, names(df)))))

## the desired output 
df[,z]
```

Comment: this works great. Thanks a lot for your support. This really relieves me of great pain. I have been trying this for a couple of days. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, you can also help by upvoting the answer and hitting the check mark below it ;)